# Как снизить загрузку памяти в системе iOS или проверить это?

Tags: ios, swift

Как снизить загрузку памяти в системе iOS?

- при запуске приложения в симуляторе Xcode 7.2 стартовая загрузка
  порядка 30МБ и затем нарастает до 300МБ.
- посмотрел в инструменте - вроде ничего особенно красного нет.
- в одном месте удалось уговорить на применение `weak var`, после чего
  загрузка снизилась до 170МБ, т.е. все-таки в памяти что-то лишнее
  сидело.
- больше weak применить не удалось - Xcode ругается типа `Thread...`

Как можно в этом вопросе поковыряться?

Comment: запустить в инструментах allocations и leaks, посмотреть что покажет.

Comment: графика тяжелая и в большом количестве - буду пробовать стричь...-спасибо за внимание...@MaxMikheyenko

Answer (score 1):

1) запусти программу на девайсе. Симулятор может работать с памятью немного по другому.
2) проверь места где ты вручную создаешь большие view или грузишь большие картинки. Будет эффект если убрать эти места или поменять размер вьюшек/картинок?